# Making url string with datepicker

Tags: iphone, xcode, datepicker, request, nsurlconnection

Hi I have made a code which gives me an url with a date at the end like www.google.com/2012-10-09

But for some reason it doesn't redirect me to the correct url?
It seems like there is some problem understanding NSURL URLwithstring?

**Here is my code**

```
- (IBAction)sedato:(id)sender {



    //Finds date and make string



    NSDate *ddato = [_datepickout date];

    NSString *vdato = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ddato];


    NSDateFormatter *datoform = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [datoform setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
    [datoform setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];

    NSDate *datemedform = [datoform dateFromString: vdato];
    NSString *strdate = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", datemedform];
    NSArray *arr = [strdate componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSString *endelig;
    endelig = [arr objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *arr2 = [endelig componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
    NSString *year;
    year = [arr2 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *mm;
    mm = [arr2 objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString *dag;
    day = [arr2 objectAtIndex:2];

   NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.coutbound.dk/logon/add_date.asp?view_date=%@/%@/%@",year,mm,day];



//Send url request with string     


    ASIFormDataRequest *request2 = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    [request2 setUseKeychainPersistence:YES];
    [request2 setUseCookiePersistence:YES];
    [request2 setDelegate:self];
    [request2 startAsynchronous];




}
    - (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
        NSLog(@"Saved form successfully");
        NSLog(@"Response was:");
        NSLog(@"%@",[request responseString]);
        NSLog(@"HEADERS: %@",[request responseHeaders]);
        NSLog(@"STATUSCODE: %u",[request responseStatusCode]);
        NSLog(@"COOkies: %@",[request responseCookies]);
    }
```

Comment: set to dateformatter your needed format yyyy/MM/dd and NSDateFormatter have method which return string from date [datoform stringFromDate: _datepickout.date]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting the date to string, then back to date, back to string, to components then again to string! There must be an error somewhere.

Try this instead:

```
NSDate *myDate = [_datePicker date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy/MM/dd";
NSString *dateStr = [formatter stringFromDate:myDate];
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", urlBase, dateStr];
```

Check the result with

```
NSLog(@"URL: %@", url);
```